# Is there a way to get the name of a prop as string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to generalize a function which is repeated 3-4 times and I am wondering if there is a way to deliberately convert property to a string containing the prop's name, to later access it.

Using something as `Type.prop.toString()` would say that I am using the type as if it was a value.

Assuming I have an `interface foo { bar: number, baz: number }`
I would need to do something as:
`foo.bar.toString()`

In order to be able to call something as:

`myFunction(foo.bar.toString())`

Which would operate as:

```
myFunction(key: string) => {
   otherFunction(this.fooInstance[key]);
   //...
}
```

**More details:**

What I am trying to do is this:

- `myFunction(foo.bar.toString());`
- `myFunction(foo.baz.toString());`

The reason why I don't do it like this (like you would do with ramda):

- `myFunction("bar");`
- `myFunction("baz");`

Is that with refactoring would make it easy to forget to update this part.

I do NOT need to do it for every key of my `Foo` class, only on a selected few ones I need to declare when calling `myFunction`.

Please if you have doubts feel free to ask, I am unfortunately not the best communicator!

Comment: `foo[bar]` is probably what you're looking for. However, we can't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: `myFunction("bar") ` ?

Comment: `a = (b, ...args) => { console.log(b, args) }` ?
`c = {d: 1}; console.log(c["d"])` ? `Object.keys(c)` ?

Comment: Pardon me, was not able to log in yesterday.

- silentw I am sorry, I am awful at expressing myself, will try to add details!
- JonasWilms that would work, the problem is that I am working on a big application and It would be easy to forget it in case of refactoring.
- Sheraff will add more details, but that is not what I am looking for, unfortunately.

(again, sorry for the lack of details, editing rn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want you do need to pass the property as a string.

So this is correct:

> ```
> myFunction("bar");  
> myFunction("baz");
> ```

To address your specific issue - i.e. support refactoring and allow only known properties - you need to tell TypeScript to restrict the value of `key` to known properties of `IFoo`:

```
interface IFoo {
  bar: number
  baz: number
}

myFunction(key: keyof IFoo){ // <-- `key` may only match the name of a property on IFoo

}
```

This addresses everything you're looking for in your question:

```
// ✔ Can only pass known property names: 'bar' | 'baz'
myFunction('bar');
myFunction('baz');

// ✔ Disallow unknown property names
// Error: '"test"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"bar" | "baz"'.
myFunction('test');

// ✔ Can refactor IFoo
// TypeScript will tell you if the string value is no longer valid
// and some IDEs will support renaming the strings when you rename the property :)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an enum and set the interface keys dynamically so you can access them as string:

```
enum FooKeys {
  bar = "bar",
  baz = "baz"
}

interface IFoo {
  [FooKeys.bar]: number
  [FooKeys.baz]: number
}

function myFunction(key: FooKeys) {
  console.log(key);
}

myFunction(FooKeys.baz);
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for, I am editing the main post to add more details, sorry for my poor communicative skills!

Comment: I think I got it now. Updated the answer for you.

Comment: still not exactly what I was looking for @Sly_cardinal solved it for me... still, upvote!